# Homeomorphism between a normed space and its open unit ball

Tags: functional-analysis

I have studied that every normed space $X$ is homeomorphic to its open unit ball $B$. I want to know what conclusion can we draw from this statement? Does it mean that every normed space is open ball? I am confused with this statement. Could anyone clear my doubt?

Thanks for help

Comment: From @Alireza Imanzadeh fard: Not true! $f$ is not well defined. Even with the real field, $X$ can not be called a scalar product of its members? Is $X$ an integer with tg(π/2||x||).x|xinX? But this may be true

f:X→B with f(x)=(1/(1+||x||).x
ker(f)=0
and
x=(1/(1−||y||)y

f and f−1 cont.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is true that every normed linear space $X$ is homeomorphic to its open unit ball $B$, for example via the homeomorphism $f:B\to X$ defined by $f(x)=\tan(\frac{\pi}{2}\|x\|)\cdot x$. This means that, *as topological spaces*, $X$ and $B$ are essentially identical. However, a normed linear space carries more information than a topological space, namely a norm. Thus the appropriate notion of "essentially identical" for normed linear space is the existence of an [isometric isomorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometry), a homeomorphism which preserves the norm. Clearly $X$ is not isometrically isomorphic to $B$, since $B$ is not even a normed linear space unless $X=\{0\}$. To see this, take any $x\neq 0$. Then $x/2\|x\|\in B$ but $2\cdot x/2\|x\|\notin B$.

Comment: As a normed linear space, $B$ isn't.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Indeed, I should probably mention that.

Comment: $B$ can't have a norm because it's not a linear space, but it does have a metric.  $X$ is not isometric to $B$ ($B$ is bounded, but $X$ is not).